# Sheet doesn't unprotect-Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, when I run the code below, I get an error saying that the sheet I am trying to change is unprotected. If I save using the Excel save option, it works fine, if I run the Macro on the sheet, I get the error saying the sheet is protected. Why would the code not recognize the part that unprotects the sheet?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim sSheetName As String
Dim logSheet As Worksheet
Dim logRow As Range
Set logSheet = Sheets("LogDetails")
sSheetName = "1107"

    Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Narrative Box"  *****Error at this line**
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Sheets("1107").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now

 Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True




End Sub
```

Comment: Is the file extension a xlsb, or xlsm? If not it is probably being blocked on purpose. Most modern excel file formats will block vba code from running. Just throwing it out there

Comment: It's .xlsm.  I am about to add an edit. I add a UserInterfaceOnly:=True when the workbook opens but now I'm getting an error when the document tries to save as...xlsm

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the issue above by adding:

```
Worksheets.protect, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

when the code opens.